# Unable to clear the Dom in Jquery Mobile based application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem to clear the DOM data.
In my jquery mobile based application.I have a first page in which I am doing some dragging of data in a particular content and take these data to second screen. From second screen if I return back to first page then I get the page with the dynamic dragged  data, but I want  the first page refreshed(Without dragged  data) like I am seeing my home page in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `data-ajax="false"` to the link to go back to the previous page, which will reload the page.

For example:

```
<a href="page-two.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Page Two</a>
```

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html